# How to add html code for symbol and not have it count that symbol when centering text?

Tags: html, css

In the code below I am running into a problem in my weather application where things are not lining up because the degrees symbol is making the numbers appear slightly off center because it is counting the degree symbol as text. It gives all the numbers the slight appearance of being off. I've tried a couple of different ways but can anyone give me a tip on how I can get the html symbol on the same line without throwing off my text centering?

```
    <div class="row">   

        <div class="panel panel-default col-md-3 plate">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title text-center"><?php echo $_SESSION['date1']; ?></h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <h1 class="main-temp"><div class="text-center"><?php echo $_SESSION['dayTemp1'] . '&#176;'; ?>
            <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="img/1.png">
            <h3 class="text-center main-weather"><?php echo $_SESSION['weather1']; ?></h3>
            <div class="row">
                <h3 class="col-md-4 text-center main-min">Min</h3>
                <h4 class="col-md-4 text-center main-humidity">Humidity</h4>
                <h3 class="col-md-4 text-center main-max">Max</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <h3 class="col-md-4 text-center main-min-value"><?php echo $_SESSION['minTemp1'] . '&#176;'; ?></h3>
                <h4 class="col-md-4 text-center main-humidity-value"><?php echo $_SESSION['humidity1'] . '%'; ?></h4>
                <h3 class="col-md-4 text-center main-max-value"><?php echo $_SESSION['maxTemp1'] . '&#176;'; ?></h3>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Add the same symbol on the opposite side and hide it with CSS, or just add some padding.

Comment: The degree symbol *is* text. That being said, instead of adding invisible characters, you can simply add a margin of 0.5em (this is a blatant guess and will depend on the font you're using anyhow) on the opposing side. Either way, it would be helpful if you could post your CSS in order to create a complete, verifyable example.

Comment: You could also just relative position it over the width of the degree symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can relative position it over by the width of the degree symbol.

```css
#containerDiv {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1em solid #000;
}

#centeredTemp {
  position: relative;
  left: .5em;
  font-size: 4em;
}
```

```html
<div id="containerDiv">
  <p id="centeredTemp">73&deg;</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This might position it farther or less over than what you need based on the text size of the degree symbol.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this, using a pseudo element with absolute position.

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  background: lightgray;
}
span {
  position: relative;
}
span:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: ' °';
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>123</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Since the temperature appears on one line, you can absolutely position the degree symbol (as seen here) without having to guess an offset like other suggestions.

Alternatively, (avoiding pseudo-elements), wrap the degree symbol, applying relative positioning to its parent and absolute positioning to the symbol's wrapper element.

Comment: @highvolt If it would be anything but a symbol, like a text, a wrapper element would likely be better, as one would want to handle that text in the markup